# use $(this) within an external function JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to target the element clicked using $(this) however I need this code to be within a function like this:

```
function openQv(){
      var  lookImg = $(this).parent().find(".look-img").attr("src");
}

$(document).on('click touchstart', '.hotspot', function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      openQv();
});
```

Using `$(this)` within an external function doesn't seem to work, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference the function and it works out of the box

```
function openQv(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var  lookImg = $(this).parent().find(".look-img").attr("src");
}

$(document).on('click touchstart', '.hotspot', openQv);
```

Or you could set the `this` value using `call`, `apply` or `bind`

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.hotspot', function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      openQv.call(this);
});
```